# Toolbar malfunction QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, toolbar, scale-bar

When adding a scale bar to the print layout, however, the scalebar just doesn't appear.

Any hints on why this would be? How to fix it?

[image: Error scalebar]

Comment: What are we seeing there? What's that dotted outline? Is the scalebar out off to the left of the screen? Is it under the map? Is it something specific to this project - what happens if you start a new QGIS project, and add one EPSG:4326 base layer, do you still get invisible scale bars? What's the settings for this invisible scale bar? What's the scale and CRS of your map layer?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right when you have the bar selected, look at the top of the page for ordering tools. Then select "bring to front".

Answer (score 3):

In the layout go to the Items panel on the right. This lists every single item in your layout (Maps, Titles, legends, etc.) in the reverse order that they are draw--i.e. items on the top of this list are rendered last so they would appear above (on top of) all items below them. Make sure your scalebar's visibility check box is checked and highlight it with your mouse and drag it it up to the top of the list.

If after all that it still doesn't show, go to the Item Properties panel and make sure it's not set to 0% opacity or something else that could be causing it not to show.